# Retrieving contents of URL after they have been changed by javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am facing a problem retrieving the contents of an HTML page using java. I have described the problem below.

1. I am loading a URL in java which returns an HTML page.
2. This page uses javascript. So when I load the URL in the browser, a javascript function call occurs **AFTER** the page has been loaded (onBodyLoad of HTML page) and it modifies some content (one of the div id's innerHtml) on the webpage. This change is obviously visible to me in the browser.
3. Now, when I try to do the same thing using java, I only get the HTML content of the page , **BEFORE** the javascript call has occurred.
4. What I want to do is, fetch the contents of the html page after the javascript function call has occurred and all this has to be done using java.

How can I do this? What should my approach be?

Comment: please simplify your question.

Comment: Its in a very simple form. Which part did you not get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this answer, Scott's answer above was a starting point for me. The Cobra project is long dead and cannot handle pages which use complex JavaScript.

However there is something called [HTML Unit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/index.html) which does just exactly what I want.

Here is a small description:

> HtmlUnit is a *"GUI-Less browser for Java programs"*. It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your *"normal"* browser.
>
> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving) and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you want to use.
>
> It is typically used for testing purposes or to retrieve information from web sites.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a server side browser library that will also execute the JavaScript, so you can get the JavaScript updated DOM contents. The default browser mechanism doesn't do this, which is why you don't get the expected result.

You should try Cobra: Java HTML Parser, which will execute your JavaScript. [See here for the download](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/java-html-parser.jsp) and for the documentation on how to use it.

**Cobra:**

> It is Javascript-aware. DOM modifications that occur during parsing will be reflected in the resulting DOM. However, Javascript can be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried using cobra? were you successful ? I am trying to use cobra, but it seems like the library is not java script aware. It could also be the case that the library is really old since it has not been modified since 2009. Is there anything else that I could try
?

Comment: @Nikhil I haven't used it in about 3 years, but I think it is still relevant for parsing most HTML documents. The trick to getting the JavaScript to work is to implement an `addDocumentNotificationListener` so you can be notified of the changes to the DOM by your JavaScript and pull in the new HTML. I don't have access to my source code for that. See [here](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp) for Incremental Rendering.